# Cisco ASA_Anyconnect clients bandwidth

Tags: cisco-asa

1. I just start managing Cisco ASA and this is my first time working with AnyConnect clients, I would like to ask how can i verify the AnyConnect client bandwidth for each user, are we able to limit each user bandwidth? I need to know what they limited that has been configured for each user.
2. we are running vASA so how can i know what ASA vm version we are running?

Answer (score 2):

Bandwidth cannot be limited on a per-user basis for AnyConnect. You could define a policy-map and class-map that limits bandwidth in some other means, such as by the subnet used for AnyConnect users, but not username.  If bandwidth is a concern, you may want to consider split-tunneling instead of tunneling all, but that may be a security concern.

You can see version info via the `show version` output.

Comment: Thank you, so if the remote has 1G up/down load in his home and other users has 500Mbs up/down. is the first users will use all the  bandwidth in anyconnect vpn?

Comment: There is no way to answer that. There are MANY other factors that would contribute to that, such as the hops in between the user and the ASA, the destination they are trying to reach and what its capabilities are, what other traffic is taking place on the ASA from anything else, etc.  In theory, one user could consume all of the bandwidth and prevent the other users from being able to function efficiently, which is where policing the traffic or using split-tunnel would come into play.